# Need help in correcting Banner Image Size

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working on a site http://www.danicatan.com

There is a random loading banner image under the navigation bar.
The actual size of the banner is 700 x 200px, but apparently the image is not displaying as per the original size, its re-sizing to 500xRelative height.

Even after given a class name of banner and setting the width to 100%, doesn't solve the problem.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

```css
.banner{
 min-width: 100% !important;
 min-height: 200px !important;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div><a href="http://www.danicatan.com/wp-content/plugins/random-image-gallery-with-pretty-photo-zoom/random-gallery/dt_2.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto" title=""><img src="http://www.danicatan.com/wp-content/plugins/random-image-gallery-with-pretty-photo-zoom/crop-random-image.php?AC=YES&amp;DIR=wp-content/plugins/random-image-gallery-with-pretty-photo-zoom/random-gallery/&amp;IMGNAME=dt_2.jpg&amp;MAXWIDTH=700"> </a></div>
```

Comment: Show your code in your question, no one really wants to click on a link to a random website and look through **all** of your code. Post relevant code here and maybe setup a demo displaying the problem and its not likely your question will be answered.

Comment: I can't view your site: 'danicatan.com is underworks, stay tuned for more details.' Maybe you could give us some code, preferable in a fiddle?

Comment: please give jsfiddle demo or your code

Comment: Ok, this is the banner class .banner{
 min-width: 100% !important;
 min-height: 200px !important;
 text-align: center;
}

Comment: Please edit your question and add the source code there.

Comment: image width and height 100%?

Comment: If you want to have the image shown x*y dimension. Have a div with min width and min height of x and y. Have the image as the div's background and set the background size as "100% auto" or whatever the order is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After putting `image { width: 100% }`. It should work properly.

Comment: I think you meant `img { width: 100% }` . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

in the file style.css ligne 300
delete

```
max-width:100%;
```

and insert

```
width:100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.banner > div > a{display:block}
.banner > div > a > img {width:100%;}
```

try this (add to your css file)